# Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKLoginManager'

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, cocoapods, fbsdkloginkit

I am integrating FacebookSDK using Cocoapods. When I create an object of `FBSDKLoginManager` like `let login = FBSDKLoginManager()` I get the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKLoginManager'". I can see autoComplete and its pointing to correct methods but it still shows the error. Here is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'BuildTheTower' do

pod 'SVProgressHUD'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

end
```

and here is my bridging header file :

```
#ifndef ObjectiveC_Bridging_Header_h
#define ObjectiveC_Bridging_Header_h

#import <SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h>

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

#endif /* ObjectiveC_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Other things such as `FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()` and `FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` are working fine but `FBSDKLoginManager` is not.

Answer (score 4):

Bridging headers are not needed. Just add import statements.

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

See the official [tutorial/docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) for more info.

Comment: Already tried that, did not work. According to my knowledge this should work if FBSDKLoginKit is in SWIFT. But the framework is in Objective-C.

Comment: @kashif789us The framework supports Swift natively. See my post edit.

Comment: This is the one I used through [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKLoginKit) I checked the downloaded source code and its .h and .m files. Should I use it without cocoapods?

Comment: @kashif789us It should work with cocoapods as well. Have you tried removing bridging headers?

Comment: it says no such module 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Comment: I commented out use_frameworks! in pod file. Did pod update and now its not showing the error. Its working fine with bridging header

Answer (score 0):

**Use these Import Statements**

```
import FacebookLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FacebookCore
import FirebaseAuth
```